# Excel 2010; multiple IF statements using "left"

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I'm trying to write this statement, please help! And as fyi, "character" refers to a number in a string of numbers in that cell. I just need to match the first number/character.

If left most character in A1 is 1, then return A in A2; if left most character in A1 is 2, then return T in A2; if leftmost character in A1 is 3; then return D in A1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
=CHOOSE(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)),"A","T","D")
```

Hope that helps